# Remote Ethernet Connection

Tags: remote-desktop, ethernet, remote-access, remote-connection

I use a laptop to program the controller in machines that we make.
The laptop connects to the machine via an standard ethernet cable.
I would like to be able to remotely access the machine once it is shipped to the customer.
The customers IT department is no help so a vpn connection is not possible, but they will provide a wifi link to the internet.
I need two devices, one that I plug my laptop into at our shop and one that resides at the customers facility that is connected to the ethernet port on the machine.
The result is... my laptop thinks it is connected directly to the machine and ditto vise versa for the machine at the customers facility.
One solution would be to use a remote laptop at the customers site and "take over" this remote laptop with software like TeamViewer. but this solution has a fatal flaw the programming software would have to reside on the remote laptop, this software is expensive and we can not afford another license
Any help or clues appreciated !

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like two Raspberry Pi's are the solution. Pre-program them to create a transparent bridged VPN between a wired Ethernet port on each end. You can use [tinc](https://www.tinc-vpn.org/) for this.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. I will look into tinc. I was hoping to find a product to purchase. Hmmm.... I will try googling Transparent Bridged VPN. Cheers !

Comment: Thanks again David, tinc looks sweet.

Comment: I was recently informed that the WiFi in the factory might block the port required for VPN. It was recommended that I use Cellular to communicate to the customers site.